# How to make generic json result print in table form with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need / or have to make a generic function that will take a generic Json Result and Print it in Table format in the order the json is returned..

e.g json might have columns "A" "B" & "C" one time. with different values and "D", "F" & "G" the other...

It should Print in Table format, how would we go about making such a generic script? or is there one available?

**UPDATE:**

I have looked for a plugin / a way to do this on google but cant find anything useful. I am not asking you to code it for me / fix it for me! give me a direction to move in  @Ji_in_coding has given a good hint in his answer of doing it myself, by making a table... and perhaps there would be a way of printing that specific div with JQuery

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us you code.  If you don't have any, then you're posting without trying, which will bear no fruit.

Comment: @Mike I might have become a bit angry in my last comment apologies.. I have searched on the web for direction, or a plugin but no clue Ji_in_coding has given a good hint / direction of coding myself 1. Converting it to a table first... and then i am thinking maybe there is a way of printing that div only..

Comment: using grid systems from  frontend libraries such as foundation or bootstrap, you can easily create tables out of divs.      [ http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html ]    [ http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid ]

Answer (score 0):

Considering a simple Json Object, there should be many examples on the internet.

```
<body>
    <div id="test">
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function jsonToTable(jsonObject){
        result = "<table>";
        for(var item in jsonObject){
            result += "<tr><td>" + item + "</td><td>" + jsonObject[item] + "</td></tr>";
        }
        result += "</table>";
        return result;
    }

    var table = jsonToTable({'cost1':12345.66, 'cost2':10.20});
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = table;
</script>
```

Comment: Please... Just don't do this... The possibilities of XSS on that are limitless!

Comment: I was considering a simple scenario. I assumed he is aggregating data from a trusted source. But oh well if you have to argue the type of usage he is using the code for .. then i suppose it's my fault for providing a ill considered response

Comment: In my opinion it's perfectly OK to say, "here's the gist of it, sort the details out yourself". But you should always stress when there is a potential security issue, because you never know what kind of environment OP is running the code in. You can hardly blame newbies for not knowing there's an issue here.

Comment: Actually this answer is giving me pretty good direction, i dont have XSS issues, as the json would be returned after security checks.. i.e. checking if user is logged on etc.

Comment: Just because someone has a registered account doesn't mean they're trustworthy. The danger here is if you're allowing users to view data that originated from other users. In that case, a malicious user could post a script saying "tell me your password"; the other user's browser would trust the script because it was seemingly from your domain. If this isn't currently possible but might be in the future, write a big note somewhere with flashing red lights saying you need to fix this. But maybe not as a comment in client-side code, you don't want to make it too easy for baddies to notice.